# Group By 2 column and Max() others in C#

Tags: c#, linq, group-by, datatable

what way that make me able to group by 2 columns and get `MAX` each other columns

lets say I have this:

```
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("s1", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("s2", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("nt1", typeof(int));
        dt.Columns.Add("nt2", typeof(int));

        // Here we add five DataRows.
        dt.Rows.Add("g1", "gg1", 1, 16);
        dt.Rows.Add("g2", "gg1", 2, 15);
        dt.Rows.Add("g1", "gg1", 3, 14);
        dt.Rows.Add("g2", "gg1", 4, 13);
        dt.Rows.Add("g1", "gg2", 5, 12);
        dt.Rows.Add("g2", "gg2", 6, 11);
        dt.Rows.Add("g1", "gg2", 7, 10);
        dt.Rows.Add("g2", "gg2", 8, 9);
```

what I'm trying to get is :

```
        g1  gg1 3   16
        g1  gg2 7   12
        g2  gg1 4   15
        g2  gg2 8   11
```

this code not work :

```
           dt = dt.AsEnumerable()
           .GroupBy(r => new
           {
               s1 = r["s1"],
               s2 = r["s2"]
           })
           .Select(x => x.Max())
           .CopyToDataTable();
```

give me error :

> Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State Error
> CS0311 The type 'System.Linq.IGrouping<string, string>' cannot be used
> as type parameter 'T' in the generic type or method
> 'DataTableExtensions.CopyToDataTable(IEnumerable)'. There is no
> implicit reference conversion from 'System.Linq.IGrouping<string,
> string>' to 'System.Data.DataRow'. testt
> C:\Users\TECNO\source\repos\testt\testt\Program.cs 44 Active

Comment: How did this fail_

Comment: I added the error message

Comment: Only `IEnumerable<DataRow>` can be converted to a DataTable. `GroupBy` doesn't return that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok this code fix the problem

thanks all

```
        var query = dt.AsEnumerable()
            .GroupBy(x => new
            {
                s1 = x["s1"],
                s2 = x["s2"]
            })
            .Select(grp => new {
                s1 = grp.Key.s1,
                s2 = grp.Key.s2,
                nt1 = grp.Max(x => x["nt1"]),
                nt2 = grp.Max(x => x["nt2"])
            });

        DataTable dt2 = dt.Clone();
        dt2.Clear();

        foreach (var item in query)
            dt2.Rows.Add(item.s1, item.s2, item.nt1, item.nt2);
```

Answer (score 1):

So, the error happens on `CopyToDataTable` because of a type mismatch. You will need to convert the result of `GroupBy` into an `IEnumerable` of `DataRow`.

I did not work in LINQ for a very long while, you will need to apply a `Select` before you call `CopyToDataTable` and make sure that you select s1, s2, Max(nt1) and Max(nt2). Maybe you will also need to call `ToList`, I'm not sure, but you will definitely need to do another `Select` after the grouping.